# How can I use UI thread in SDI project

Tags: c++, mfc

[Sample Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BHzd-hoIuafbV28OD7OpnbWAssFQ54oP/view?usp=sharing) Working on Visual studio 2008.

I need UI thread to modify SDI project. 
I've used in before Dialog based project. In SDI project, I can create thread but I can't use it.

I create Manager Dialog.

**SDIProjectView.cpp**

```
int CSDIProjectView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    m_pViewMgr = new CDlgViewMgr(this);

    m_pViewMgr->Create(IDD_DIALOG_VIEWMGR, this);
    m_pViewMgr->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

    return 0;
}
```

In Manager Dialog, create thread dialog.
When I call ShowWindow m_pDlg->hWnd is invalid value.
What's the best way witout user action?

**CDlgViewMgr.cpp**

```
BOOL CDlgViewMgr::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    m_view = new CDlgThread(this);
    m_view->CreateThread();

    m_view->m_pDlg->ShowWindow(SW_NORMAL);
    return TRUE;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep all GUI objects in the main thread and other heavy works in a separate thread to make the application responsive. Creating the child dialog in a worker thread will invite trouble and is not recommended.

Also, avoid calling ShowWindow() in CWnd::Create(). You can't request to show a child windows before the parent windows is full ready.

Comment: Thank you. I got an idea. And When is the best time to call ShowWindow()?

Comment: After calling CDialogEx::OnInitDialog() pertaining to the parent windows. Otherwise if a timer is associated with the parent windows, you can call once during it's idle time.